# comparing modem.oqpsk probability error and ber

Tags: matlab, simulation, signal-processing, signals, telecommunication

hi currently i have the following code in my matlab

```
        values = [0;1;0;0;1;0;1;0];   % can contain only 0s and 1s
        h = modem.oqpskmod;
        y = modulate(h, values);
        g = modem.oqpskdemod(h);
        z = demodulate(g,y);
        BER = sum(logical(values(:)-z(:)))/numel(values);% thanks to gnovice!
```

now my question is how can i compare this BER to the Probability Error of the OQPSK?

Comment: I don't understand the question. "Compare" in what sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've run a number of different sets of `values` through the modulation/demodulation process above, the resulting average BER measure **is** an estimate of the bit-wise probability for an error to occur.

Perhaps you are wanting to compare the above *estimate* to an actual derived *formula* for what the expected error rate is? [This Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-shift_keying#Bit_error_rate_2) says that the probability of bit-error for QPSK (and I assume also for OQPSK) is given by the formula:

```
Pb = Q(sqrt(2*Eb/N0));
```

where the function `Q` and the parameters `Eb` and `N0` are described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-shift_keying#Definitions).